# How Delete Last number of a float in android (java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am building a calculator app and everything is working properly but I don't know the code for backspace.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // UI Elements

    private TextView num_input;
    private TextView num_input;
    private ImageButton num_backspace;

    private float input, input2 ;

    boolean Addition, Subtract, Multiplication, Division, mRemainder, decimal, add_sub;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing
        num_input = findViewById(R.id.num_input);
        num_output = findViewById(R.id.num_output);
        num_backspace = findViewById(R.id.num_backspace);


        num_backspace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            //TODO: the backslash code goes here.
        });

    }
}
```

I tried doing this

```
num_backspace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            input = Float.parseFloat(num_input.getText() + "");
                String sample_input = Float.toString(input);
                sample_input = sample_input.substring(0,sample_input.length() - 1);
        });
```

Some help would be great!

thanks in advance

Comment: Floats do not now about a limited number digits. When showing Floats to the user, they should be rounded strings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to store `input` as a String, not float. Because before you start doing mathematical calculations it's just a String input, and "backspace" means basically removing one character, it's not a mathematical operation. So, provided `input` is a String, backspace code will be:

```
input = input(0, input.length() - 1);
num_input.setText(input);
```

And before doing calculations convert your String input into float via

```
float operand = Float.parseFloat(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this code inside your setOnClickListener

```
String value =  num_input.getText().toString();
if (value != null && value.length() > 0 ) {
    value = value.substring(0, value.length() - 1);
}
num_input.setText(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

How this is usually done is getting the current value (entered number) in the TextView, remove the last character from the string and writing it back to the TextView.

Comment: it doesn't work and also it's data type is float

Comment: The result num_input.getText() is a String. Do the removal of the last character before turning it into a float.

Comment: it would be great if you you could post an example here